# Where are the latest ASP.NET MVC bits?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Are the latest bits for MVC the Preview 5 release? I've been out of the loop for a while and just wanted to make sure I had the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the download like: [Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A24D1E00-CD35-4F66-BAA0-2362BDDE0766&displaylang=en)

The main site is [www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Source code is here: [www.codeplex.com/aspnet](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to hold off before you do a new install as the Release Candidate is shipping soon (whatever that means). Watch some videos, read some articles ...

Or go get the beta and dive in...